# Portfolio Allocation Optimization in R

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio

The main purpose for which I need R is porfolio allocation optimization (non-linear system).
In fact, my input is a variance/covariance matrix (size (n=50) 50*50) to which I would like to apply the "Equal Contribution to Risk" code (risk parity technique for which each asset contribute for the same amount of risk).

The output should be optimal weights per asset, and I get error message.

May you help on the code? Does not seem too much complicated, but I am not at ease enough with R...

[problem formulation here](http://www.thierry-roncalli.com/download/rmetrics-risk-parity.pdf). Go to slide 32 of Roncalli presentation.
with `b[i]=1/n`

Comment: euh... what code? what error message?

Comment: I am looking for a code in order to be able to obtain the optimal weights under the ERC conditions (cf slide 32 of the link). Moreover, there are more constraints given that each weight has to lay between 0 and 5%. May you help on that? I think it is possible to get inspiration from the existing code herebelow the webpage: http://zoonek.free.fr/blosxom/R/2012-06-01_Optimization.html     .Thanks a lot to all!